# Redirection after loggin not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem with the redirecton after a seccesful login.
Basicly what I wnat to do is when the user enters his userName and his Login, the query search in the table, and retrieves the adequate role, and based to that role, it redirects the user to his specific folder.
 I am trying this code

```
private void imgBtnLogin_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
   FormsAuthentication.Initialize();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=.; initial catalog = AxaStock; integrated security = true");
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "select r.nomRole from Collaborateur c, Role r where r.idRole=c.idRole and matricule=@matricule and password=@password";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@matricule", SqlDbType.VarChar, 64).Value = txtLogin.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 128).Value = txtPassword.Text;

    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, txtLogin.Text,
            DateTime.Now, 
            DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), 
            true, 
            reader.GetString(0),
            FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
        string hash = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hash);
        if (ticket.IsPersistent) cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        string returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];


        if (returnUrl == null)
        {
            returnUrl = "/";

        }
    }
    else
    {
        lblError.Text = "Matricule / mot de passe incorrect. Réssayez !";
        lblError.Visible = true;
    }
    reader.Close();
    con.Close();


}
```

My Web.Config

```
<system.web>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" loginUrl="Login.aspx"  protection="All" path="/"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
</system.web>
  <location path="TP">
  <system.web>
      <authorization>
          <allow roles="Technicien de proximité"/>
          <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
  </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="CDP">
      <system.web>
          <authorization>
              <allow roles="Chef de projet"/>
              <deny users="*"/>
          </authorization>
      </system.web>
  </location>
```

When I click the button login, it doesnt redirect me to the specific folder, it Stays in the Login page without giving me any message. How can I do to be redirected to TP/Accueil.aspx ?? 
please help

Comment: you are missing             `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtLogin.Text, false);`

Comment: You are not redirecting any where in the code.

Comment: Where should I add that code ?? @VikasRana

Comment: @VikasRana I did what you told me but and finally it leaves the login page, but it redirects me to another page which is not in the folder that I want !!

Comment: @user3759974 by this code you are redirecting to url in txtLogin. see my answer for code

Comment: You must use hashing and add a salt to your password. Storing password in plain text in your database is very insecure. Please see article about password hashing: http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/06/our-password-hashing-has-no-clothes.html Also please consider using a framework for managing your users, like ASP.NET Identity - makes your job much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You are not redirecting anywhere in your code. your code authenticate the user. store its information into cookies. try this

```
  if (reader.Read())
    {
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, txtLogin.Text,
            DateTime.Now, 
            DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), 
            true, 
            reader.GetString(0),
            FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
        string hash = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hash);
        if (ticket.IsPersistent) cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        string returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtLogin.Text, false);

        if (returnUrl == null)
        {
            returnUrl = "/";

        }
    }
```

also in your `Web.Config`. add this to `<system.web>`

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" name="logck">
      </forms>
  </authentication>
```

From msdn

> in the URL http://www.contoso.com/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=caller.aspx,
>   the RedirectFromLoginPage method redirects tothe return URL
>   caller.aspx. If the ReturnURL variable does not exist, the
>   RedirectFromLoginPage method redirects to the URL in the DefaultUrl
>   property.
>   Set desired url into your return url parameter.
>   for more info read  [RedirectFromLoginPage.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka5ffkce%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: LEmme explain to you the structure of my project 
There is the root, login.asp my web.config, Global.asax, contact.aspx, default.aspx(an empty page) and there is folders named by roles : a folder "TP", "CDP", "GS" each one of these folders have it's own welcome.aspx page.
When the user clicks on login button ,and by adding the method you told me, it redirects to the default.aspx page, which is not the page  I want, in the matter fact it must redirect me to the TP/welcome.aspx

Comment: here is my Web.config 

   ` <authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms name="MYWEBAPP.ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="Login.aspx"  protection="All" path="/"/>
  </authentication>
  <authorization>
   <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
     <location path="TP">
   <system.web>
    <authorization>
     <allow roles="Technicien de proximité"/>
     <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
   </system.web>
   </location>
   <location path="CDP">
    <system.web>
     <authorization>
      <allow roles="Chef de projet"/>
      <deny users="*"/>
     </authorization>
    </system.web>
   </location>`

Comment: Still redirects me to Default.aspx :(

Comment: @user3759974 the problam is in your return url see example and msdn page i updated in answer.

Comment: @user3759974 also see `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtLogin.Text, false);`

Comment: I've read the MSDN and edited the code, and effectively the URL changes, but I still don't know why it doesn't show me the welcome page. It's like it's stuck in the login !!

Comment: @user3759974 see if yopu autherize the user to enter that folder or not in your web.config?

Comment: I have updated my question, i added my web.config could you please go check. thank you

Comment: I added a defaultUrl="TP/Welcome.aspx" in web.config and changed the deny users to "?" it worked, but when I rechanged it to "*" it gives me the the correct URL and I keep getting redirected back to my login page. here is the URL 
http://localhost:59887/AxaStock/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fAxaStock%2fTP%2fAccueil.aspx